# Preserving scaling of multiple items in set with Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a set of several shapes each scaled in different rates.

When the set transformed to another point using

```
set.transform("tp1,p2")
```

shapes rescale to their normal sizes. For each of the shapes scaled 
in different proportions of their original sizes, i can not give a scale 
option to set.transform.

How can i preserve scaling of each item in set during transform()?

My question in code:

http://jsfiddle.net/XHr4H/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael's imperfect way of dealing with this is to allow transformation directives to be either prepended to the transform sequence (using "directive...") or appended to the transform sequence (using "...directive").  In your case, the simplest way to achieve the effect you're after is to prepend the relative transform you want in your setTimeout function.

```
var paper = Raphael("paper", 200, 200);

var s = paper.set(),
    r = paper.rect(0,0,30,30).attr({"fill":"green"}).transform("t27,30s0.2"),
    r2  = paper.rect(40,0,30,30).attr({"fill":"red"}).transform("t27,30s0.4");
s.push(r,r2);
setTimeout(function(){
    s.transform("t100,150...");  // here 'tis
}, 2000);
```

The transform("t100,150...") essentially inserts the desired translate into the beginning of the transform string for each element in the set.  Thus, `r`'s transform evaluates cumulatively to "t127,180s0.2" and `r2`'s becomes "t127,180s0.4".

Comment: hm actually i've seen "..." in documentation and thought it was there as a placeholder for the previous transform text, put in order not to write it again :) thank you.